# Unemployment with Blue card in Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card, unemployment-benefits

I'm a Blue Card holder in Germany since October 2018, when I started working.

In 2019 I switched my employer without problems.

Unfortunately, in March of this year I was told my contract would be ended on 30th April due to Corona crisis. Since then, I started looking for a new job, but due to the situation the quest took longer than expected. This month I've got an offer from a good command, but the starting date will be on September 1st. The Ausländerbehörde has already issued a new Zusatzblatt authorising switching to the new employer at this date.

Now comes my issue: I've applied and have been granted the unemployment benefit (Arbeitslosgeld I) since May 1st. But the Blue card role says I can have it for three months at most:

[image: rules for blue card]
[image: artikel 13]

I have requested an exceptional extension to the Arbeitsamt but they told that they cannot do anything to me in this case, as it would go against the Blue card rules. So what am I supposed to do to in August? Unfortunately I depend on the ALGI at the moment to the financial support of my family.

Comment: Their explanation is complete BS. The only thing the directive say is that you cannot be stripped of your Blue Card and forced to leave the country during this three months. It doesn't that you have to be if unemployment lasts more than three months and it doesn't say anything at all about unemployment benefits. Unfortunately, this also means that it doesn't give you any leverage but just that they are perfectly allowed to pay if they want to (as other member states do in this situation).

Comment: In your situation I would go to a good lawyer (search on anwalt.de for the lawyers specialised on labour and immigration laws). If you are a PhD student, you can first try to go to the lawyer from university (for free, but usually useless and specialised on student rights, do not trust them too much)

Comment: I'm a PhD student, and I thought the same, so I did not try it yet. If things get really tricky, I'll try to find a good/ specialized lawyer at anwalt.de - thanks for the suggestion